# Looking for alternatives to MySQL Workbench to work with MariaDB 10

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a tool that can be an alternate for MySQL Workbench to work with MariaDB 10.  Problem is, the latest MySQL Workbench 8.x is not compatible with MariaDB 10.  So any suggestions on this would be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one https://mariadb.com/kb/en/graphical-and-enhanced-clients/
try to check each option to see which is suitable for you

Comment: Just ran into this issue with MySQL Workbench latest update flatly refusing to connect to my GoDaddy Potatoe powered MariaDB. I can recommend [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) from the above link, took about 5 mins to setup and for my use works near enough the same. 

If like me and you are using an SSH Tunnel, ensure you also have [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) installed as you'll need `plink.exe` to handle the connection in the `SSH Executable` option field.